# Prediction based on multiple binary inputs

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, logistic-regression

Assume we have following DataFrame, where A, B, C, and D are the binary outcome of a classification task. "1" relates to "finished", "0" relates to "not finished".

```
A B C D True
0 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1
0 1 0 0 1
0 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
0 1 0 0 0
```

I wonder how possible it is to predict the `True` outcome, dependent on the values in `A, B, C, D`.

Shall I apply a multivariate logistic regression with `scikit learn`?

Comment: Not really an SO question

Comment: But CrossValidaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [sklearn's `LogisticRegression`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html):

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

endog = data.TRUE.values
exog = data.drop('TRUE', axis=1).values
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(exog, endog)

model.score(exog, endog)  # mean accuracy
# 0.90909090909090906

model.predict(exog)       # your predicted values
# array([1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int64)
```

Keep in mind in this example you are training a statistical model and then trying to predict based on the (in-sample) data you've already fed the model.  **That is generally regarded as shabby statistical practice, so proceed with caution** or test on out-of-sample data.

Comment: I fully understand your comment. I also see the limitations, however, a reviewer asked for it.

Comment: Is there a way to get probabilities, rather than binary predictions?

Comment: Yes @Christoper.  http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict_proba